# "...I expected would come" or "...I would have expected to come"?

Tags: grammar

Example:

> Of all the people who wanted to join the trip, Jane was the last one I
>   expected would come.
>
> Of all the people who wanted to join the trip, Jane was the last one I would have
>   expected to come.

I suspect one of them is grammatically incorrect, though I'm not sure which one.

Answer (score 3):

They are both correct, and have similar meanings. In most cases you could use either one. There is a subtle difference, however:

> Of all the people who wanted to join the trip, Jane was the last one I expected would come.

This suggests that you *did not* expect Jane to come.

> Of all the people who wanted to join the trip, Jane was the last one I would have expected to come.

This suggests that *had you thought about it*, you would not have expected Jane to come.

So they both imply that you are surprised that Jane wanted to come (or are unsurprised that she didn't want to come), but the first suggests that you had thought about it earlier and decided Jane was unlikely to come.

The meanings are close enough that most of the time it wouldn't matter which one you used.

Just another point is that you could exclude the word *one* from these sentences. That is,

> Of all the people who wanted to join the trip, Jane was the last I expected would come.

is a valid sentence. Since you have established that you are talking about someone from the group of "people who wanted to join the trip", it is implied that "the last" refers to "the last person from this group".